# Is it Possible to calculate different business hours, based on different queues and different time zones?

Tags: timezone, businesshours

Can we calculate different business hours, based on different queues and different time zones?

Please Help me!!

Comment: Madhuri, could you provide some more information about what you're trying to do ? Right now it's not entirely clear what you mean by "based on queues and time zones". By providing more details you help us help you.

Comment: ok samuel! we have different projects like Disti, Canada.... for Disti which is in queue, the support is only 8hrs IST and for Canada 24hrs support US time. so we need to calculate business hours for both which are on different timezone and queues.

Comment: It’s a part of SLA Automation
Scenario:  the company/production  has default business hours 24.
Can we calculate different business hours, based on different queues and different time zones?
e.g: for queue: disti, only 8 hrs, IST
                Canada, 24hrs support, US
If yes, what are the steps to achieve this?
If No, reasons why can’t we do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on timezone mapping with business hours, you can implement this in Apex using the BusinessHours class.

Please refer the links below.
https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#CSHID=apex_classes_businesshours.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fapex_classes_businesshours.htm|SkinName=webhelp

http://salesforcery.blogspot.in/2011/10/business-hours-and-holidays.html